# Unable to make my spider run written in combination with splash

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy, scrapy-splash

This is my first time to work with scrapy-splash to parse the name and price of different products from a javascript enabled website. The selectors I've used in my script is flawless which I've already tested using selenium. However, when I run my script, it throws an error shown below. I've attached a log file which is the total status of my spider's collection. Is there anything else I need to do for the successful execution of my spider. Thanks in advance.

Here is the script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest

class RedmartSpider(scrapy.Spider):
  name = 'redmart'
  start_urls = ['https://redmart.com/bakery',]

  def start_requests(self):
    for url in self.start_urls:
      yield SplashRequest(url, self.parse, args={'wait': 0.5})

  def parse(self, response):
    for item in response.css(".productDescriptionAndPrice"):
        name = item.css("h4 a::text").extract_first()
        price = item.css("[itemprop=price]::text").extract_first()
        yield {"Name":name,"Price":price}
```

What I've added to the `settings.py`:

```
SPLASH_URL = 'http://192.168.59.103:8050'
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}
```

This is the partial error log:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\ar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 1384, in _inlineCallbacks
    result = result.throwExceptionIntoGenerator(g)
  File "c:\users\ar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\twisted\python\failure.py", line 393, in throwExceptionIntoGenerator
    return g.throw(self.type, self.value, self.tb)
  File "c:\users\ar\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\downloader\middleware.py", line 43, in process_request
    defer.returnValue((yield download_func(request=request,spider=spider)))
twisted.internet.error.TCPTimedOutError: TCP connection timed out: 10060: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond..
```

This is the [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/w16q25jlrts376x/output_file.log?dl=0) to the log file.

Answer (score 0):

Your `SPLASH_URL` might be wrong, that IP is the same the one used as an example for documentations.

If you're running the Splash container with `docker run -p 8050:8050 scrapinghub/splash` your `SPLASH_URL` should be `http://localhost:8050`.